# join in mysql select more row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

1)Table for category --> prenotable_services

2)Table for product --> services

I want to get on category query all products.

**prenotable_services**
[image]

**services**
[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT p.*, s.promo FROM prenotable_services p, services s WHERE p.id = s.categoryID
```

The result:
[image]

This because in the services table there are more row with same categoryID.

**I want to get the products ONCE TIME with promotion and not promotion, but only once time.**

Comment: You'd get more attention if you post those data samples in textual format instead of images. Simply because if someone wants to help, it's quicker to copy and paste texts than to re-write whatever on your image. And honestly, question like this is not just being easily ignored by many but it's also a downvote magnet.

Comment: As for your expected result output, it's best to illustrate them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT p.*, s.promo FROM prenotable_services p, services s WHERE p.id = s.categoryID AND s.promo="true"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the results must return regardless of whether promo is true or false